# ¿Qué palabra para "cremallera" o "cierre" se usa con más frecuencia al hablar informalmente en México?

Tags: coloquialismos, sustantivos, ropa

La palabra de mas frecuencia de ingles de Estados Unidos es "zipper":

[image: picture of a zipper]

*Esta imagen de un cierre es propiedad de la Fundación Wikimedia. La fotografía es segura de usar (no se viola la ley de derechos de autor).*

Comment: cremallera viene de fermeture à crémallière en francés. Pues, se usa en España.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Cierre» es lo que se utiliza en esta región.